# Checked checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have checkbox assigned to color. Yesterday I added 8 colors and 2 more this morning. I copied the code for other colors and i just changed value to assign it to the good color. my problem is that for the color pink and orange i get the error message TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
    at myFunc (https://replit.org/data/web_hosting/NoobCode/Color/index.js:36:24)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick (https://replit.org/data/web_hosting/NoobCode/Color/:238:36)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
Black<input type="checkbox" id="BLACK">
___Blue<input type="checkbox" id="BLUE">
___Red<input type="checkbox" id="RED">
___Yellow<input type="checkbox" id="YELLOW">
___Green<input type="checkbox" id="GREEN">
___Purple<input type="checkbox" id="PURPLE">
___Brown<input type="checkbox" id="BROWN">
___Pink<input type="checkbox" id="PINK">
___Orange<input type="checkbox" id="ORANGE">
___Erase<input type="checkbox" id="PINK">
```

after i have a table with lot of time the same thing

```
<table >
        <tr>
    <th onclick="myFunc(this)"></th>
    <th onclick="myFunc(this)"></th>  
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
 td, th
{
   border:solid black 1px;     
   width:950px;
   height:26px;


}

table
{
     border-collapse: collapse;

}

.thBlack
{
background-color:Black;
}
.thBlue
{
    background-color:royalblue;
}
.thYellow
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
.thRed
{
    background-color:#f72213;
}
    .thGreen
{
    background-color:green;
}
    .thPurple
{
    background-color:purple;
}
.thBrown{
    background-color:#6b461a;
}
.thWhite{
    background-color:white;
}
.thOrange{
background-color:#ff8c00;
}
.thPink{
    background-color:hotpink;
}
```

Javascript

```
var checkBLACK = document.getElementById("BLACK");
var checkBLUE = document.getElementById("BLUE");
var checkRED= document.getElementById("RED");
var checkYELLOW = document.getElementById("YELLOW");
var checkGREEN = document.getElementById("GREEN");
var checkPURPLE = document.getElementById("PURPLE");
var checkBROWN = document.getElementById("BROWN");
var checkPINK = document.getElementById("PINK");
var checkORANGE = document.getElementById("ORANGE");
var checkWHITE = document.getElementById("WHITE");

function myFunc(elem) {
if (checkBLUE.checked == true){
elem.classList.toggle("thBlue");
}

else if(checkBLACK.checked == true){
         elem.classList.toggle("thBlack");
}
 else if(checkGREEN.checked == true){
         elem.classList.toggle("thGreen");
}

else if(checkYELLOW.checked == true){
         elem.classList.toggle("thYellow");
}
 else if(checkRED.checked == true){
         elem.classList.toggle("thRed");
}
 else if(checkPURPLE.checked == true){
         elem.classList.toggle("thPurple");
}
else if(checkBROWN.checked == true){
         elem.classList.toggle("thBrown");
}
else if(checkWHITE.checked == true){
         elem.classList.toggle("thWhite");
}
else if(checkORANGE.checked == true){
         elem.classList.toggle("thOrange");
}
else if(checkPINK.checked == true){
         elem.classList.toggle("thPink");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check your repl error it seems that the error is in the line 36 of your function. This line here:

```
else if(checkWHITE.checked == true){
```

the var `checkWHITE` is defined as:

```
var checkWHITE = document.getElementById("WHITE");
```

but `document.getElementById("WHITE");` is returning null

This is happening because you don't have any element with the id WHITE only have these colors:

```
Black<input type="checkbox" id="BLACK">
___Blue<input type="checkbox" id="BLUE">
___Red<input type="checkbox" id="RED">
___Yellow<input type="checkbox" id="YELLOW">
___Green<input type="checkbox" id="GREEN">
___Purple<input type="checkbox" id="PURPLE">
___Brown<input type="checkbox" id="BROWN">
___Pink<input type="checkbox" id="PINK">
___Orange<input type="checkbox" id="ORANGE">
___Erase<input type="checkbox" id="PINK">
```

So just go and add this to your html:

```
___White<input type="checkbox" id="ORANGE">
```

And everything should work fine

Comment: Thanks it worked, but im so confused. i looked for the error for about 45 minutes, i tried thing and changed some. I add the element with id white, im sure about this, but i have no clue of why it wasnt working why i add it.